# C++ Destructor Conventions

Tags: c++, destructor, conventions

I see a lot of code like the example below in C++, which is usually recommended as a convention:

```
class Foo
{
public:

    Foo()
    {
        bar = new int[100];
        size = 100;
    }

    // ... copy/assignment stuff ...

    ~Foo()
    {
        if (bar) // <--- needed?
        {
            delete[] bar;
            bar = nullptr; // <--- needed?
        }

        size = 0; // <--- needed?
    }

private:

    int* bar;
    int size;
};
```

To me, the three statements `if (bar) { ... }`, `bar = nullptr;`, and `size = 0;` are redundant for two reasons:

1. `delete nullptr;` is prefectly safe, and it doesn't do anything.
2. If the object is destroyed and the memory is released, I shouldn't worry about safety to set `bar` to `nullptr` and `size` to 0.

Are these justifications correct? Are these statement truly redundant? If so, why do people keep using and suggesting them? I would like to see some potential problems that could be solved by keeping this convention.

Comment: Why? Because they're 40+-yo creatures of habit who spent their youth writing C and never really trusted that "scary C++ monster with all its templates and overloads" and would much rather you just use naked pointers.

Comment: Yes, these statements are redundant. On the other hand, that `delete` is incorrect, and should be a `delete[]`.

Comment: `delete bar` is all you need. And unless there's a possibility that your pointer is deleted before the destructor is called, the `if` is pointless as well.

Comment: @BoBTFish You're right about the `delete[]`. Oops!

Comment: @KerrekSB: Alternatively they're 20+-yo youngsters who learned from 40+-yo creatures of habit who lost interest in widening their horizon after getting their first job and then permanently insist on having so much experience that learning more after uni is unnecessary or on having no time to read books this phrase no comma.

Comment: Just curious, who's recommending this convention to you? Except for the one case described in an answer below, it's total rubbish.

Comment: @MarkRansom People I trust (or rather used to trust) with C++ knowledge. I also just see it used very often in code I work with.

Comment: @phresnel: yes, indeed, transitively so...

Comment: Utter waste of time. And an indication that whoever wrote it isn't thinking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, those aren't needed and some compilers will optimize them away anyway.

**However** - the reason people usually do this is to help spot out problems. For example, say you don't set the pointer to null. The object is destroyed, but then you *incorrectly* attempt to access the (what once was) pointer. Since the runtime will probably not clear it, you'll still see something valid there. This is only valuable from debugging, and it's still undefined behavior, but it sometimes pays off.

Comment: `if(bar)` is useless for debugging, `0`/`nullptr` is probably the *worst* value you can use to mark the memory as *destroyed* (some implementations already do this for you with a more interesting bit pattern: `0xDEADBEEF`, at the very least you want the last bits to be set to mark the pointer as invalid...)

Comment: This answer would be perfect if it were used as a platform to extoll the virtues of avoiding all this crap in the first place by using `unique_ptr`, `vector`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Where is this `usually recommended as a convention`?

What's usually recommended is to NOT manually manage memory allocation. If you used a `std::vector` (or smart pointer if you really want) to implement this, all the problems go away completely and you don't need to write a destructor at all.

However if you're *really* insisting on doing this (and you've written copy constructor/copy assignment you haven't shown us, for correctness), then I find that the extra work in the destructor actually hides what's really happening and provides little value at the expense of code obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `delete[]` (array)

It's true that the `if` is useless. Impact in terms of performance can usually be neglected. When you debug, You are sometime happy to have things in a safe state (like prevent to look at some freed memory and scratch your head). When it's hidden deep inside a tree, it helps (at least reinitializing the size and bar).

BTW, better way of writing it would be (RAII : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization )

```
Foo(): 
  bar (new int[100]),
  size(100)
{
}
```

*EDIT* :

- old habits die hard, for this you should used a `scoped_ptr` and be happy with it (or even better, a `vector`) and kill plain old dumb pointers.
- older guys written too much C or swap between too many languages : better safe than sorry when it's cheap

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in many other answers, the `if(bar)` is rather silly.

Setting freed pointers to `nullptr` and resetting `size = 0` has its uses though.  Some of those redundancies are good in OOP when you have virtual constructors, virtual destructors, and class hierarchies.  During a destructor, what happens if a child class frees a pointer but doesn't set it to `nullptr`, and then a base class tries to free it as well?  In a similar case, what happens if a base class *assumes* that a pointer is valid if `size > 0`?

There are minor bookkeeping details like these that can create subtle bugs that are extremely hard to debug.  Might as well be pedantic in some of these cases and let the compiler take away what is not necessary.

Comment: "During a destructor, what happens if a child class frees a pointer but doesn't set it to nullptr, and then a base class tries to free it as well" - it signals out a bad logical but because you'll most likely get a crash because of a double delete. Why would a child destroy something owned by a parent?

Comment: I don't really see why a child would release a parent member either. That just screams bad design to me.

Comment: In large and complex programs, there might be multiple pointer instances to the same data location.  If just one child/object frees his instance, the base's instance silently becomes invalid as well.  If everyone was a perfect programmer, then the world would be a much better place, but alas it is not so.  These redundancies can help mitigate the consequences of less bright co-workers during the initial development stages.

Comment: @Aggieboy setting your version of the pointer to `nullptr` doesn't affect any other copies of the pointer, so that convention wouldn't help you with the dull co-workers either.